# Filter Control with Select all

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I created the following control:

```
public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new();
```

```
<CollectionViewSource
    x:Key="UsersKey"
    IsLiveFilteringRequested="True"
    Source="{Binding Users}"/>
```

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControlUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Users}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Checked="CheckBox_OnChecked" Unchecked="CheckBox_OnUnchecked" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And this is how it looks:

[image: An ItemsControl with multiple items displayed as a checkbox with label.]

And I want to add a CheckBox of **Select all**.

I would like it to look like this:

[image: An ItemsControl with multiple items displayed as a checkbox with label and an item at the top labelled "Select all".]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious solution would be to just use a `StackPanel` add a `CheckBox` before the `ItemsControl`. In this case the item does not belong to the `ItemsControl`. Whether this is acceptable or not depends on your requirements.

```
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel.Resources>
      <CollectionViewSource
         x:Key="UsersKey"
         IsLiveFilteringRequested="True"
         Source="{Binding StringItems}"/>
   </StackPanel.Resources>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <CheckBox Content="Select all"/>
   </StackPanel>
   <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControlUsers">
      <!-- ...other markup. -->
   </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Another solution is to use a [`CompositeCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-a-compositecollection?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) that allows you to bind multiple collections and also add single elements. All of the items are then part of the `ItemsControl`.

```
<Border>
   <Border.Resources>
      <CollectionViewSource
         x:Key="UsersKey"
         IsLiveFilteringRequested="True"
         Source="{Binding Users}"/>
   </Border.Resources>
   <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControlUsers">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
         <CompositeCollection>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <CheckBox Content="Select all"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource UsersKey}}"/>
         </CompositeCollection>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Checked="CheckBox_OnChecked" Unchecked="CheckBox_OnUnchecked" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
</Border>
```